# What exactly does a non-shallow filecmp.cmp do?

Tags: python, filecompare

I'm using Python 2.6.2. The [docs for the filecmp module](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/filecmp.html) say:

> The filecmp module defines functions to compare files and directories, with various optional time/correctness trade-offs.

and, of the filecmp.cmp function:

> filecmp.cmp(f1, f2[, shallow])
>
> Compare the files named f1 and f2, returning True if they seem equal, False otherwise.
>
> Unless shallow is given and is false, files with identical os.stat() signatures are taken to be equal.

What they don't do is specify just what is the correctness level one obtains with `shallow=False`. So, what does `shallow=False` do? How correct is it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consulting the [source `filecmp.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/filecmp.py) reveals that if `shallow=False`, `filecmp.cmp` first checks a few select properties of `os.stat()`, regardless of whether `shallow` is `True` or `False`. If the stat properties that are examined are the same, it returns `True`. Else, it checks its internal cache to see if the files have already been compared earlier. If it has, it returns `True`. Else, it reads `BUFSIZE = 8*1024` chunks of data from both files and does an exact contents comparison until it reaches the end of the file. It returns `True` if the two files have exactly the same contents.

Comment: I have recently clarified this in the official documentation of Python 3.3

Comment: How and when will one need to do a 'shallow comparison' between two files? The only difference of this would be it also regard 'mode mtime size' equality as file equality, well, but this doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @RobertBean It saves you a lot of processing time. I think they determined that most of the time files with identical signatures are in fact identical.

Comment: @NullUserException Since the os.stat includes inode number, then os.stat would only be the same if the files are hardlinks, correct?  (Though this may vary with filesystem, and os.stat follows symlinks?)

Comment: for non-shallow mode, why not compute hash of both files and compare? Won't that be faster